# How do you add elements to a set with DataStax QueryBuilder?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have a table whose column types are

```
text, bigint, set<text>
```

I'm trying to update a single row and add an element to the set using QueryBuilder.

The code that overwrites the existing set looks like this (note this is scala):

```
val query = QueryBuilder.update("twitter", "tweets")
  .`with`(QueryBuilder.set("sinceid", update.sinceID))
  .and(QueryBuilder.set("tweets", setAsJavaSet(update.tweets)))
  .where(QueryBuilder.eq("handle", update.handle))
```

I was able to find the actual CQL for adding an element to a set which is:

```
UPDATE users
SET emails = emails + {'fb@friendsofmordor.org'} WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

But could not find an example using QueryBuilder.

Based off of the CQL I also tried:

```
  .and(QueryBuilder.set("tweets", "tweets"+{setAsJavaSet(update.tweets)}))
```

But it did not work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `add` (add one element at a time) or `addAll` (<strike>more than one</strike> any number of element at a time) method to add to a set.

Answer (score 1):

To extend [Ananth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30420946/4021802):

`QueryBuilder.add` does not support `BindMarker`. To use BindMarker while adding in set, it is required to use `QueryBuilder.addAll` only.*

*Just a note, `Collections.singleton` may come in handy in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Ananth and @sazzad answers, the code below works:

```java
Session cassandraSession;
UUID uuid;
Long value;

Statement queryAddToSet = QueryBuilder
        .update("tableName")
        .with(QueryBuilder.addAll("setFieldName", QueryBuilder.bindMarker()))
        .where(QueryBuilder.eq("whereFieldName", QueryBuilder.bindMarker()));

PreparedStatement preparedQuery = cassandraSession.prepare(queryAddToSet);
BoundStatement boundQuery = preparedQuery.bind();

boundQuery
        .setUUID("whereFieldName", uuid)
        .setSet("setFieldName", Collections.singleton(value));

session.execute(boundQuery);
```